# cannot upgrade linux kernel to newest version

Tags: boot, kernel, updates

My current kernel version shown by `uname -r` is: 3.5.0-17-generic.
However, there are files related to newer version kernel 3.5.0-26 in /boot. So I want to upgrade the kernel to 3.5.0-26 by running: `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic`. But it shows:

```
linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic`, then re-install it by `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic`. This time, I can install the newer kernel, but `uname -r` stil shows 3.5.0-17. I didn't try the other way around, that is, removing kernel 3.5.0-17-generic, since it is the currently used one, I am afraid removing it might cause problems.

So I am confused. If linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic is already the newest version, why `uname -r` shows 3.5.0-17 that is an older version?

PS: before this, I have no space problem in /boot, and I cannot update any packages. As I said, my current kernel version is 3.5.0-17. But there are many files related to newer version kernels, ranging from version 3.5.0-18 to 3.5.0-26. So I found a script to remove all of them, but files related to 3.5.0-26 are still there.

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall package? You can try it by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)`. Also, you can try t *fix* problems by adding `-f` argument.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that with --reinstall and -f options. Then I install the newer 3.5.0-26 kernel by `sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-26-generic`; there is an error that shows the kernel header files are not found. So I also install the kernel header packages, then reinstall 3.5.0-26 kernel. However, `uname -r` still shows 3.5.0-17.

Comment: So, maybe it's some kind of problem with linux kernel package itself? Have you tried to install another version?